# How to pass Scenario out line data as a object in step method using cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am finding a solution to pass each scenario outline example row as object in cucuber-jvm.

So as for example if I consider a scenario

```
Scenario Outline: example
Given I have a url 
When I choose <input_1>
Then page should hold field1 value as <validation field1> field2 value as <validation field2> fieldn value as <validation fieldn> 

Examples:
| input_1        |  validation field1 |validation field2|validation field n|
| input_1_case_1 |  expected value 1  |expected value 1 |expected value n  |
```

So in Step file

```
public void validationMethod(String validation field2,String validation field2,String validation field3){
............
............
}
```

So if I have more field then my method also consume more argument.

Now I want to pass all validation field as object in method. So is it possible using cucumber jvm? If possible could any one can please provide some suggestion with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
Then Use the following values
| <validation field1> | <validation field2> | <validation field3> |

Examples:
| input_1        |  validation field1 |validation field2|validation field3 |
| input_1_case_1 |  expected value 1  |expected value 2 |expected value 3  |
| input_2_case_2 |  expected value 1  |expected value 2 |expected value 3  |

Step Definition
@Then("^Use the following values$")
public void useFollVal(List<String> valFields) {
     //The values will be inside the list. Use index to access

}
```

You can even get an validation object instead of string list ie `List<ValidationData>`. To do this add a **header in the step** (not the examples table) with names matching the variables in the `ValidationData` class and cucumber will populate the data into the object.

```
Then Use the following values
| valField1 | valField2 | valField3 |   <<<--- Header to add 
| <validation field1> | <validation field2> | <validation field3> |     

        valField1 -> private String valField1; in ValidationData

    Step Definition
        @Then("^Use the following values$")
        public void useFollVal(List<ValidationData> valObject) {

        }
```

Comment: awesome solution thanks for your helpful comment. But I have a question regarding the later part where you provide the solution using ValidationData object. I could not understand that if I not provide the data in examples part then how cucumber iterate the scenario with the following data? because data table not used for iteration.

Comment: @saba My bad... Poor choice of words. What I meant was that cucumber will match the variables from the header in the step and not the one in the examples table. Offcourse you will need the header in the examples table else this will not work. I have put the whole step in my answer now.

Comment: Thank you. you are genius. you use lamda expression to create that DTO So you use Java 8. I am using Java 7 So I create this using Inner DTO class or separate POJO class.

Comment: No Java8, I was just pointing out with arrows for emphasis. Inner class could work though never tried it though. Always used a separate POJO.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment: Wouldnt a variable length argument list work for you? You would need to know the sequence of your params though, without the argument names to help out.

```
public void multiParams(String... val){

}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but using this I am getting Arity mismatch error.